# Create React App with react-svg-loader without ejecting fails when trying to minify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am using `create-react-app` to build my React application. I've added `react-svg-loader` and using it in this way:

```
export { default as arrowLeft } from '-!react-svg-loader!./arrow-left.svg';
export { default as arrowRight } from '-!react-svg-loader!./arrow-right.svg';
```

But when I am trying to run `yarn build` - process fails on minification step:

> Creating an optimized production build... Failed to compile.
>
> Failed to minify the code from this file:
>
> ```
>     ./node_modules/react-svg-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/icons/arrow-left.svg:6
> ```
>
> Read more here: http://bit .ly/2tRViJ9

Can I fix it somehow **without** ejecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found is [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) + [react-app-rewire-svg-react-loader](https://github.com/codebandits/react-app-rewire-svg-react-loader). Inside `config-overrides.js`, which is used by this library you will have an access to webpack config. So it can be easy changed.

My config looks like this:

```
const rewireSvgReactLoader = require('react-app-rewire-svg-react-loader');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  return rewireSvgReactLoader(config, env);
};
```

Comment: You're essentially "ejecting", which is what you described what you didn't want to do in the OP

Comment: @oshikryu check carefully. I am not ejecting. I am changing "react-scripts" to "react-app-rewired"

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I was about to give up and eject!

Comment: The project `react-app-rewire-svg-react-loader` has been archived. The author said it is because Create React App v2 introduced support for SVG Components

Answer (score 0):

Not directly but yes, give this a try https://github.com/kitze/custom-react-scripts its a fork of react-scripts (the config that powers create-react-app) but extended for you to add new features to it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's just another scripts with some additional features. And SVG support is not inside

Comment: That is correct but also not correct, yes they provide some built in drag and drop solutions but they also leave the config open for you to hook on things:

https://github.com/kitze/custom-react-scripts/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L244

At least it works in pointing out how you could do it yourself 

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable eslint at the top of the file where you import your svg

```
/* eslint import/no-webpack-loader-syntax: off */
```

Comment: Where you see ESLint here? How it is related to my question?

Comment: @oshikryu I did run into this issue. Thank you for mentioning this workaround. I'd forgotten you could do this with ESLint. Sadly, CRA is still not running svg-react-loader for me. I'll have to do more research.

Answer (score 0):

I just switched to `@svgr/webpack`, and it works perfectly fine for me.

So for your code, you'll have to do this:

1. Install `@svgr/webpack`.
   `yarn add @svgr/webpack`
2. Make changes to your exports.
   `export { default as arrowLeft } from '-!@svgr/webpack!./arrow-left.svg';`
   `export { default as arrowRight } from '-!@svgr/webpack!./arrow-right.svg';`
3. `yarn build`

I tried this with the `material-design-icons` package.
My code is as follows:

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-webpack-loader-syntax */

export { default as PlusButton } from '-!@svgr/webpack!material-design-icons/content/svg/production/ic_add_24px.svg';
export { default as MoreButton } from '-!@svgr/webpack!material-design-icons/navigation/svg/production/ic_more_horiz_24px.svg';
export { default as CloseButton } from '-!@svgr/webpack!material-design-icons/navigation/svg/production/ic_close_24px.svg';
```

To me, this required the least amount of changes.
I'm still in CRA, and neither had to make no changes to react scripts, nor swap it out for an alternative like `react-app-rewired` or something.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for this now, they added support for this in 2.0.0, see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs